# Writing Conditional Django Views

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have been racking my brain all day to get past a few challenges in my project.  I have a view that is currently a ListView, but I need to display conditional logic as well and I am too much of a noob with Django, I'm not sure of the questions to ask.

Displaying the list in my template is the easy part, but if you look at the code below, I also have a centext total_sales defined to aggregate the sum of the 'sales' column - this also works.  What I need is to be able to display the Sum *if* the 'day_of_week' field == "Monday" or any other day of week in the *if* statement.

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I realized my question didn't include enough information.  'day_of_week' is a field in the Traffic model and I would like to show the Sum of the 'sales' field, but only if 'day_of_week' is equal to a specific day.  I am new to Django and although I know how to write *if* statements, I am completely unsure how to place them in my view in this instance so I can render the totals in my template.

Is there a way to write conditional data in the view how I currently have it setup?  Thank you for your time.

```
class TrafficListView(ListView):
    model = Traffic
    template_name = 'dashboard/pages/traffic.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TrafficListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['total_sales'] = Traffic.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('sales')).get('sales__sum', 0.00)
        return context
```

Comment: Sorry, once more I'm not entirely following. Is `day_of_week` a field on the Traffic model? And where is "Insert Day Of Week" coming from?

Comment: the view is python code, you can do conditional in python... I fail to see the difficulty?  or maybe you want to do it in the template instead https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've added an UPDATE to my question with more detail. Also, the "insert day of week" was not literal, it just meant to reference Monday, Tuesday, or any other weekday I need to have in the 'if' statement.

Anentropic - thank you for your link, i did see this and it seems appropriate, but I am new to Django and the Django documentation isn't always clear enough to understand where and how to use the code.

Comment: I understand it's not a literal, but I'm still confused about where it's coming from. Is it a URL parameter?

Comment: We run large email and adword campaigns and the reports we generate have day_of_week as one of the fields so we can compare the success of our campaigns against the day the campaign was ran.  Part of the dashboard I am creating will list the entire report traffic in TrafficListView; there are a total of 10 fields in the report.  Since it would be difficult to manually add all the site traffic generate from each day the campaign was ran, I am creating a widget that will display the total traffic from each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to display the total sales for each day of the week and not a particular day as you mentioned in the comments above, you can do the following:

```
class TrafficListView(ListView):
    model = Traffic
    template_name = 'dashboard/pages/traffic.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TrafficListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday'] # days of the week
        total_sales = {} # create an empty dictionary 
        for day in days:
            # get the sales for that particular day 
            total_sales[day] = Traffic.objects.filter(day_of_week=day).aggregate(Sum('sales')).get('sales__sum', 0.00)
        context['total_sales'] = total_sales # pass 'total_sales' dictionary in context
        return context
```

Here, we create a list `days` having values from `Monday` to `Sunday`. Then we create an empty dictionary `total_sales`.

We will now iterate through the `days` list and filter all the objects from `Traffic` model where `day_of_week` is equal to that particular day.
 lets say `Monday`. Then we perform `Sum` aggregation on the objects returned for `day_of_week` as `Monday` on the `sales` field. The value returned from `sales_sum` is stored in a key `Monday` in the `total_sales` dictionary. So, after iteration is complete, there will be 7 keys in the `total_sales` for each day of the week with the value being the sum of sales for that particular day.

**In your template**, use `{{total_sales.Monday}}` to access `Monday` sales, `{{total_sales.Tuesday}}` for `Tuesday` sales and so on.

Comment: If I could buy you a beer, I would...you are a rock star!! Thank you for the answer, but also thank you for including the template info and the comments in the code so I know what you were doing.  This but of code is going to help me build all my other widgets.  Thank you again!!